# How to find objects inside a tablespace without using DBA_SEGMENTS

Tags: oracle, data-dictionary

[DBA_SEGMENTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_4264.htm) just shows objects that already have some associated extent (and so, it's considered a segment).

#### Demo

Creating a new tablespace:

```
SQL> create tablespace manu datafile size 20m;

Tablespace created.
```

Creating a new table (without any inserts, so no extent will be created).

```
SQL> create table foo.t1 (id int) tablespace manu;

Table created.
```

Trying to drop tablespace (without specifying "including contents")

```
SQL> drop tablespace manu;
drop tablespace manu
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01549: tablespace not empty, use INCLUDING CONTENTS option
```

How can I map objects and tablespace without using DBA_SEGMENTS?

The first idea was to check [DBA_OBJECTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1158.htm#REFRN20146), but there is no column about which tablespace the objects are associated with.

Is there other view I can use?

I am able to drop the tablespace after dropping the table.

```
SQL> drop table foo.t1;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop tablespace manu;

Tablespace dropped.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DBA_TABLES
DBA_INDEXES
DBA_LOBS
DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS
DBA_IND_PARTITIONS
DBA_LOB_PARTITIONS
DBA_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS
DBA_IND_SUBPARTITIONS
DBA_LOB_SUBPARTITIONS
```

You may also want to check the below for default tablespaces of partitioned objects:

```
DBA_PART_TABLES
DBA_PART_INDEXES
DBA_PART_LOBS
```